# How to Synch SPSS and SQL Data

Tags: sql, spss

I imported SQL data to SPSS for analysis and made lots of changes in the field names, types and ...

However, it happens a lot that some records in SQL database are added/removed and these changes must be reflected into my SPSS file. I know that I can export back my SPSS to SQL, make changes there in SQL, and import back SQL data to SPSS. But, every time I import it, all the lables, classifications and ... revert back.

So, I am wondering if at all there is a way to synch records (or even fields) from SQL without importing new SQL table in a fresh SPSS file?

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using triggers. I understand that in some relational databases, such as Oracle, you can write to a file after each update/insert/delete.

Comment: SPSS file format is not text-based and cannot be opened in notepad or similar apps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-import the table, but as long as your changes are made in syntax, you can just reexecute that syntax to reapply the changes.  Alternatively, if you can identify the changes based on date or other criteria, you could just pull those changes, apply your syntax, and merge with the main file using MATCH, ADD, or UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks JKP, won't re-importing table change the setting ? I guess it does, right?

Comment: If you reexecute your saved syntax, you will get all the selected records, and the syntax would still run as long as the field names or data types have not changed.